# ComboBox not changing when bound value of SelectedItem changes

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that has its `ItemSource` and `SelectedItem` properties bound to a view model.  And I have the following block of code that is the callback for a data query against a `DomainContext`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores (readonly) - Stores available for ship to store.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<StoreEntity> Stores
    {
        get { return _stores; }
        private set { _stores = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Stores"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SelectedStore - Currently selected store.
    /// </summary>
    public StoreEntity SelectedStore
    {
        get { return _selectedStore; }
        set { _selectedStore = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStore"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When stores are completely loaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_loadOperations"></param>
    protected void OnStoresLoaded(LoadOperation<StoreEntity> a_loadOperations)
    {
        Stores.AddRange(a_loadOperations.Entities);
        SelectedStore = a_loadOperations.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

In this example, `Stores` is a `ObservableCollection<StoreEntity>` (`AddRange` is an extention method) and is bound to `ItemSource`, and `SelectedStore` is a `StoreEntity` and is bound to `SelectedItem`.

The problem here is that the `ComboBox` is not changing its selection to reflect the change in `SelectedItem`.

**Edits:**

I've even tried the following, though I think that `a_loadOperation.Entities` is already a realized set:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// When stores are completely loaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_loadOperations"></param>
    protected void OnStoresLoaded(LoadOperation<StoreEntity> a_loadOperations)
    {
        var entities = a_loadOperations.Entities.ToArray();
        Stores.AddRange(entities);
        SelectedStore = entities.First();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems that everything is set up correctly. Can you show us the xaml part where you set the binding?

Comment: Did you set the binding mode to two way

Comment: In our explenation you call it SelectedItem, but the property is called SelectedStore - double check your xaml to see if this isn't the case there.

Comment: Ah! I figured out my problem.  I had `SelectedItem` bound to `Stores`.

Comment: @EtherDragon, `SelectedItem` is a property on the `ComboBox` and `SelectedStore` is a property in my view model bound to `SelectedItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `SelectedItem` bound to `Stores` instead of `SelectedStore`.  Ooops!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a change to your viewmodel (specifically the SelectedStore property) to be reflected in your combo box, you could:

1. Confirm the binding worked.  Check it was set up properly in the XAML, and check the Output window to see if there is a message saying the Binding failed
2. Confirm your DataContext is set properly (it probably is since you are getting the combo box `ItemsSource` from `Stores`
3. Subscribe to your PropertyChanged event and confirm that it is being raised when the property changes

If that doesn't work, it may be a bug with the ComboBox.  I have seen cases where the order of specifying the properties in XAML makes the difference (ex: you should set ItemsSource first and SelectedItem second).  I have also seen a binding fail until I added Mode=TwoWay (even though in your example you are trying to get the binding to update from your view model to your UI).  Try confirming that your ComboBox XAML is like this:
`<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stores}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStore, Mode=TwoWay}" />`
Order shouldn't matter since XAML is declarative, but I have personally seen it matter with ComboBoxes in Silverlight.

Comment: As I stated before you wrote your answer,  I figured this out on my own. Se comments in question post.  Thanks.

Comment: I see your comment from 4 hours ago which says that you found the problem.  However, I wrote my response 16 hours ago.  At any rate, glad you figured it out.  Bindings can be especially tricky since you don't get much feedback about why they aren't working.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  I didn't see it until later.